# How to update database records after the initial data entry

Tags: php, mysql

I'm using a form to enter data about projects that my company is working on (in reality it's for a class project).  I have multiple projects from multiple clients.  The insert form has 4 fields that must be filled in when each project is entered into the database.  The database table has 7 total fields, with the last 3 being updated as the project progresses. I didn't add them to the insert form because they aren't necessary there.  I don't have any problems entering each project into the database initially, but I need to be able to update the other 3 fields as each respective project goes through various stages of completion.  Here's the initial insert form.

```
    <h2>New Project</h2>
    <p class="first"><span class="error">* required field.</span></p>
    <form action="http://www.oldgamer60.com/Project/NewProject.php" method="post">

<div class="fieldset">
        <fieldset>

        Project: <input type="text" name="Project" value="<?php if(isset($Project)){ echo $Project; } ?>">
        <span class="error">* <?php if(isset($ProjectErr)){ echo $ProjectErr; } ?></span>
        <br><br>
        Client: <input type="text" name="Client" value="<?php if(isset($Client)){ echo $Client; } ?>">
        <span class="error">* <?php if(isset($ClientErr)){ echo $ClientErr; } ?></span>
        <br><br>
        LastName: <input type="text" name="LastName" value="<?php if(isset($LastName)){ echo $LastName; } ?>">
        <span class="error">* <?php if(isset($LastNameErr)){ echo $LastNameErr; } ?></span>
        <br><br>
        DateReceived: <input type="text" name="DateReceived" value="<?php if(isset($DateReceived)){ echo $DateReceived; } ?>">
        <span class="error">* <?php if(isset($DateReceivedErr)){ echo $DateReceivedErr; } ?></span>
        <br><br>
        <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit"> 
     </fieldset>
    </div>
    </form>
<br>

<?php
function test_input($data){
   $data = trim($data);
   $data = stripslashes($data);
   $data = htmlspecialchars($data);
   return $data;
}

$servername = "localhost";
$username = "xxx";
$password = "xxx";
$dbname = "oldga740_SeniorProject";

// create connection
$connection = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);

if(isset($_POST['submit']) && !$connection->connect_error){
    // to track errors
    $error = false;

    // now validate input fields
    if (empty($_POST['Project']) || !isset($_POST['Project'])){
        $ProjectErr = "Project name is required";
        $error = true;
    }elseif(!preg_match("/^[a-zA-Z\s]{1,}$/",$_POST['Project'])){
        // check if project only contains letters and whitespace
        $ProjectErr = "Only letters and white space allowed";
        $error = true;
    }else{
        $Project = test_input($_POST['Project']);
    }

    if (empty($_POST['Client']) || !isset($_POST['Client'])){
        $ClientErr = "Client name is required";
        $error = true;
    }elseif(!preg_match("/^[a-zA-Z\s]{1,}$/",$_POST['Client'])){
        // check if client only contains letters and whitespace
        $ClientErr = "Only letters and white space allowed";
        $error = true;
    }else{
        $Client = test_input($_POST['Client']);
    }

    if (empty($_POST['LastName']) || !isset($_POST['LastName'])){
        $LastNameErr = "Last name is required";
        $error = true;
    }elseif(!preg_match("/^[a-zA-Z\s]{1,}$/",$_POST['LastName'])){
        // check if last name only contains letters and whitespace
        $LastNameErr = "Only letters and white space allowed";
        $error = true;
    }else{
        $LastName = test_input($_POST['LastName']);
    }

    if (empty($_POST['DateReceived']) || !isset($_POST['DateReceived'])){
        $DateReceivedErr = "Data received field is required";
        $error = true;
    }elseif(!preg_match("/^[a-zA-Z\s]{1,}$/",$_POST['DateReceived'])){
        // check if data received only contains letters and whitespace
        $DateReceivedErr = "Only letters and white space allowed";
        $error = true;
    }else{
        $DateReceived = test_input($_POST['DateReceived']);
    }

    if(!$error){
        $query = "INSERT INTO Projects (Project, Client, LastName, DateReceived) VALUES ('$Project', '$Client', '$LastName', '$DateReceived')";
        if($connection->query($query)){
            echo "record is successfully inserted!";
        }else{
            echo "error: record could not be inserted";
        }
    }
}

?>



<?php
    $connection->close();
?>
</div>
<div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: do you want to do this at db level or by code?

Comment: UPDATE table_name
SET column1=value1,column2=value2,...
WHERE some_column=some_value;

Comment: @davejal my plan is to do it all by code.  I thought to just use a simple query to show a status of all the projects and then use an update table to do the appropriate changes.  I just thought there might be a better way to do it.

Comment: As the answer is Already given by @MarkNg I think he should write it as an answer for you. Basically you will write an update query to update the records in your db

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
//fetch whatever data you want to update.....
//all your arguments before you set var
//...


//set var field to update
//$fielddata1=$_POST['fielddata1'];
//more var.....
//set var for project name to update <- important, this tell the db which row to update. see query below

//if($Project){}; or wrapping your query to be executed only in an argument = true might be something you can consider as well.
$query = "UPDATE Projects Set 
        ColumnName1 = '$fielddata1',
        ColumnName2 = '$fielddata2',
        Columnname3 = '$fielddata3'
        WHERE Project = '$Project'";
        //this part WHERE CLAUSE is VERY VERY important, missing the WHERE CLAUSE can cause all row to be updated.

if($connection->query($query)){
            echo "record is successfully inserted!";
        }else{
            echo "error: record could not be inserted";
        }
//rest of your code...
```

Comment: By fetching whatever data I want to update, do you mean run my select query?  I know I have to build a form to process the updates.

Comment: eg: u already query and fetch a form, then u change the value and submit your edited form to this code for update into db

Comment: I'm learning this as I go so please don't think I'm just trying to be a pain.  I know I already have the form built to do the initial update.  Are you saying that I call the data into that form, then re-submit is as an update?

Comment: No worries, yes, that is what you will do, and submit to this code as update.

Comment: I'm having difficulties incroporating your suggested coding.  I'm using drop down menus right now to populate tables that display my query results, and I thought I could use a drop down menu in my projects form to pull records into the form using the primary key, which is project.

Comment: how are u fetching the records now?

Comment: I'm running queries using menu's with drop downs that have select options.  Those options are linked to pages on my server where I have the php and sql set up to run the queries.  I'm having those results displayed in tables on the page the query was called from.   I have forms set up to allow me to insert new records to the database